# strange error in list class

Tags: c++, list

I build my project. it has no error except one that it say it is in list class! the default list class not mine.
the error is

Error   1   error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'moveStringTree' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Wild question... do you have an operator `==` that takes a `moveStringTree` as parameter?

Comment: Please post the code too causing the error.

Comment: the strange part is there is just that error. it doen't indicate any part of my code that causes this error. when I click on error it opens list class

Comment: Man we are not god!!! your 20 min back question was also a black box.

Comment: "click on error"… this is how errors are dealt with nowadays…

Comment: I said. I clicked on that. and it opened list class. please read my comments before offending me.

Comment: @Anonymous: I said. there is really no other information. there is only just one error that I copied it completely. and when I click it, it just opens list class

Comment: Have you considered answering @LuchianGrigore's question? The thing is that error occurs during an attempt to instantiate the template and that puts some obligations on your class. In particular it is expected to have an operator `==` that takes a `moveStringTree` as a parameter.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I never used any == in my code on moveStringTree

Comment: Can you reduce the code to a minimal complete example, and post that?

Comment: Maybe not explicitly...\

Comment: @Beta it has more than 5000 lines. impossible to reduce it to few lines.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: is it possible that it is used in remove(x)?

Comment: It is *not* impossible to reduce 5000 lines to a few, while still reproducing the error. It *is* impossible for us to diagnose this problem without any code to look at.

Comment: @Anonymous : thanks god I didn't get any more down vote for this one. even I didn't get why I get down-votes for my last question. could you please tell me?

Comment: Yes. It can be used by containers.

Comment: @Beta: I think it is produced by a .remove(). I only guess this.

Comment: @Masoud:- Black box perhaps!!!

Comment: Then remove the `.remove()`, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @Beta: No. It is solved by removing it.

Comment: It seems some people are misusing their power to down-vote.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: so should I overwrite ==?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::list::remove` depends on the == operator to correctly associate the object passed to an object in the list. Define this in your moveStringTree class:

```
bool operator==( const moveStringTree& other ) const  {
    return x == other.x;
}
```

Where x is the value you want to compare.

If you want to remove the object only if it is the same instance, compare the pointers.

```
return this == &other;
```